# Change variable value if all value inside an object are same and false or true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent form component and a child form field component.

The child field component processes a form field, validates the input, and returns back the value with an error which is true if there is an error or false if there isn't.

After processing the output of all fields the formData looks like:

An invalid output

```js
formData: {
    email: {value: "", error: true}
    first_name: {value: "", error: true}
    last_name: {value: "", error: true}
    password: {value: "", error: true}
}
```

A valid output looks like

```js
formData: {
    email: {value: "myemail@gmail.com", error: false}
    first_name: {value: "NameFirst", error: false}
    last_name: {value: "NameSecond", error: false}
    password: {value: "StrongPassword@", error: false}
}
```

What is the best way using react to

- set `formValidated: false` if all or one of the error values are true
- set `formValidated: true` if all of the error values are false

Comment: You would probably only want to set `formValidated: true` if all of the error values are false. Not just if one of them is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you asked for the best way, but I'm not sure how to evaluate that. Here is a way. I can't imagine you can get your answer without looping through every `error` property and checking if its `true`.

The below code will short circuit the loop if one `error` is `true` to shorten the loop. If you want all possible errors to surface at the same time you can change the `return false` in `isFormValid` to something that will track the errors and return that at the end of the loop.

```js
let formObj = {
  formData: {
    email: {
      value: "myemail@gmail.com",
      error: false
    },
    first_name: {
      value: "NameFirst",
      error: false
    },
    last_name: {
      value: "NameSecond",
      error: false
    },
    password: {
      value: "StrongPassword@",
      error: false
    }
  }
}

function isFormValid() {
  for (let [formName, formValue] of Object.entries(formObj.formData)) {
    if (formValue.error) {
      console.log(`${formName} is invalid`);
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

let isValidForm = isFormValid();
console.log(`is valid form: ${isValidForm}`);
```

Comment: dont you think ``formName, formValue`` should be ``fieldName, fieldValue`` for better semantics

Comment: @FahadSohail You can name it whatever you want, this is just an example.